# La forma más eficiente de realizar peticiones a un servidor?

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un cliente web que consume una REST API, el punto es que para realizar las peticiones utilizando Fetch (En javascript) me han pedido que realice todas estas desde un solo archivo javascript ... pero no termino de entender, debo crear una petición con cada tipo de elemento que se necesite? ... imagino que quieren dar la idea de un patrón de diseño pero no me queda claro cual

un solo .js con un montón de metodos en donde se use fetch muchas veces? o existe una manera mas optima de realizar esto?

Comment: Creo que lo que trata de decir es de mantener todas las URL de las peticiones en un mismo archivo y en vez de hacer todo en diferentes archivos, unificarlo para que cuando un servicio se modifique sea más fácil de encontrarlo y cambiarlo.

Comment: para luego solo llamar estos metodos donde los necesite?

Comment: Claro, quisiera creer que es eso. Mantener todas esas rutas en una función y luego llamarlo.